# Dynamically update sql columns based on number of entries

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to create a table like below:

```
id| timestamp | neighbour1_id | neighbour1_email | neighbour2_id | neighbour2_email 
and so on upto max neighbour 20.
```

I have two questions:

1. Should I create columns statically or is there a way to create columns dynamically using php based on the count of json Array?
2. In either case, how would I refer to the columns dynamically and assign value to them based on jsonArray?

My jsonArray would look something like:

```
{id:123, email_id:abc, neighbours: [{neighbour1_id:234, neighbour1_email: bcd}, {neighbour2_id:345, neighbour2_email:dsf}, {}, {}...]}
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is you should absolutely not do that using columns, but you **should** research database normalization and use relational tables

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to rethink your database structure a bit. To me it looks like you need a single users (or whatever they are) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cretaed_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And another table that defines relations between those users:

```
CREATE TABLE `neighbors` (
  `parent` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `child` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`child`)
);
```

Now you can add as many neighbors to each user as you want. Fetching them is as  easy as:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `neighbors` ON `users`.`id` = `neighbors`.`child`
WHERE `neighbors`.`parent` = ?
```

Where that question mark would become the id of the user from which you are fetching the neighbors, preferably by using a prepared statement.

If it is all JSON you will be working with, and querying isn't much of an issue, you could consider working with a noSql database or document store (like redis or mongoDb), but that is an entirely different story.

Just repeating a bunch of columns x times is definitely not the way to go. Vertical size (# rows) of tables in relational databases is no big issue, they are designed for that. Horizontal size (# columns) however is something to be careful with, as it may make your db uanessacry large, and decrease performance.

Just consider what you would if you want to find a user that has a neighbor with an email address [x]. You would have to repeat your where statement 20 times for each possible email column. And that is just one example...

Comment: Let me provide more details of my situation. Here the primary user is the base device. And the neighbours are the nearby devices. I have to sample the data in every 1 minute to send the signal strength of the neighbours with respect to the base device. This is a interval collection where I need to record data dynamically. So, my neighbours will keep changing very frequently. And I also need past data.

Answer (score 0):

well, the answer i was working on while pevara was posting theirs faster is almost the same...

```
CREATE TABLE `neighbours` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `neighbour_email` char(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `neighbour_email_collections` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `email_id` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `neighbour_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`neighbour_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into neighbours values (234, "bcd");
insert into neighbours values (345, "dsf");
insert into neighbour_email_collections values(123, "abc", 234);
insert into neighbour_email_collections values(123, "abc", 345);

select      * 
from        neighbours 
left join   neighbour_email_collections 
on          neighbour_email_collections.neighbour_id=neighbours.id
where       neighbour_email_collections.id=123;
```